# How we can remove the back texture in libGDX?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

```
private Texture  druidTexture;
private SpriteBatch batch;    
Sprite sprite;
@Override
public void create() {
druidTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("star-large.gif"));    
sprite = new Sprite(druidTexture);
batch = new SpriteBatch(); 
}
@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    batch.begin();
    sprite.rotate(45);
    float x=sprite.getX();
    float y=sprite.getY(); 
    float newx=x+1;
    System.out.println(newx);
    float newy=y+1;
    sprite.setX(newx);
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

}
```

i am getting output for the above code as this
[image]

but i need to remove the star at back,for each star,how can i do that??

Comment: It seems you want to clear the screen before each frame. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch) how to do it.

Comment: @Banthar : this for the link , Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); this code help,can u post it as an aswer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clear the screen before each frame as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch):

```
    public void render () {
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // This cryptic line clears the screen.
            batch.begin();
            // Drawing goes here!
            batch.end();
    }
```

Comment: how can detect is the texture is at end of the form, if so, need to stop rendering, how can we do that?

Comment: That's an entirely separate question, and it depends on your projection matrix. If it's the default OpenGL projection, you'd just check when the star's position is >= 1. If you're projecting to 1 unit = 1 pixel, you would check when the star's position is >= width of the window. For any other projection, you'd have to do some math to see where the edge of the window is first.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the screen firstly in function `render`

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         .....
}
```